# Why doesn't p4 sync -f folder revive a deleted folder?

Tags: perforce

(foo is source controled)

```
$ rm -rf foo
$ p4 sync -f foo
$ ls foo
ls: cannot access foo: No such file or directory
$ p4 sync -f foo/...
$ ls foo
bar.txt
```

Comment: Can you edit your question and make 'g4' read 'p4'. Also, what does the first 'p4 sync' say?

Comment: Sorry, g4 is Google's p4. The first sync says `file(s) not in client view.`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perforce doesn't know about [directories](http://kb.perforce.com/article/966/adding-empty-directories), that's why it cannot 'revive' them. The second sync succeeds, because you are not syncing the directory, but the files in this directory.

The directory `foo` wasn't added with p4 initially. It was probably added by `p4 add foo/bar.txt`

Comment: That's what I figured, just wanted confirmation. Thanks.